# How to deploy .net8 & python3 azure function apps to a Elastic app service plan?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

How can I deploy two different stack .net8 and python 3 azure function app to a elastic app service plan?

I tried there is no way to add python to .net8 together, at least not find the way on azure portal.

I tried to get both of them in a single app service plan on azure portal, however, did not find the option to do.

creating new .net azure app is allowed to assign to existing elastic app service plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it isn't possible to run apps for two different languages on the same app, you can deploy two separate apps (one for each stack you have) on the same elastic app service plan.

Since the pricing for compute is at the plan level, you can deploy as many apps as you want to the same plan. If you are using the Dedicated or Premium App Service Plan, this is simple to do while creating the function app from the portal.

But if you are simply using the Consumption Plan, this is not possible from the Portal directly today. Instead, you can use Azure CLI (`az functionapp create`) to create a new function app and associate it with an existing consumption plan resource, using the `--plan` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Pramod. Is it possible to have .net & python azure functions in same Elastic app service plan? I did not find a way to add them together.

Comment: As long as they are separate function apps with the same operating system (windows vs linux), you can deploy both apps to the same app service plan.

Comment: Yes, that is possible if one azure function app in .net then another azure function app .net can be added the same app service plan, however, I want to add python azure function app to existing .net azure function app in one elastic app service plan.

Comment: That won't work unfortunately. Why do you need them to be on the same function app though?